# Light ray through glass tube

Tags: geometric-optics

Is there a way possible that light ray goes from glass tube to air undeviated in a straight line? I made few ray diagram but could not find a possible way

Comment: Do you really mean a light ray (infinitesimally thin and not physically possible), or do you mean a light beam, like the beam from a laser pointer?  Ìf the latter, do you mean a perfectly cylindrical glass tube or do you mean a tube with some other shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: when the light ray is perpendicular to the tube surface.